# Mouse not working in flash, Ubuntu!

Tags: ubuntu, flash, webcam

Clicking buttons as on youtube works fine. The problem is that with chatroulette I have to allow flash to access my webcam. That box there is unclickable and I have tried everything.

Comment: Could you be more specific what eactly your problem and what your setup is? What hardware? Any special drivers?

Comment: Rants are likely to get closed as not a question.  If you are looking for help please be more specific with your question.

Comment: I updated with more details.

Comment: I never had problems with Flash in Ubuntu, other than that the wheel also triggers scrolling in Firefox. But well, Flash player is not open source, so Ubuntu developers can't do anything about bugs in it.

Answer (score 0):

The deal is that Ubuntu apparently by default install the pluginwrapper. So I did not get native flash on my 64-bit box. When I installed the native version everything works perfect.:)